# Scripting github commands with no SSH Key password

Tags: git, github

If I do not set a passphrase for the SSH Key generation what risks do I run?

The reason I am choosing not to use a password is ease of configuration for scripting git pull and push events on a windows laptop with python.

Comment: I never really set up a passphrase when setting up SSH Keys, never had an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The risk that if someone gets a hold of your key (Via malware, for instance) they can impersonate you, check in to your repo, etc.

That said, I would *really* nervous about leaving a non-passworded key on a Windows machine. I do it all the time on unix (including OS X) machines I control, but I feel much better about the security of those systems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to balance between the security and ease of use. I have seen that passphrase-less ssh keys for git access are pretty common, mainly because of the convenience. I would rather have a passphrase-less one than try to use some hacky means of trying to script the push and pull.

Just make sure the keys are only kept within your $HOME folder on Windows and you should be pretty secure.

If someone has access to your private folder, you will have bigger problems to deal with anyway.